# What module lets you delete a node after a specific time if its unpublished?

Tags: nodes

is there a module that can delete or prune nodes that does not get published after a certain amount of time has passed? Currently the node prune module doesnt work with the latest core release. Looking for alternatives if possible.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using the Rules module.  If you enable the built-in scheduler submodule, you could create a set of rules/components like this (rough code to give you an idea, not a step-by-step walkthrough):

Component to delete content (Action set)

- Action: Delete content

Rule to schedule content deletion (Rule)

- Event: Content is created
- Action: Schedule the "Component to delete content" after the specified amount of time

Rule to clear deletion on publishing (Rule)

- Event: Content is published
- Action: Delete the scheduled event for that piece of content ("Component to delete content")